# In a reusable component Angular directive which wraps another directive, how can I make a model "pass through"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In Angular, I'm creating a directive for a reusable component that wraps [`ui-select`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) (to automate integration with REST services).  My directive will be invoked roughly like this:

```
<rest-backed-selector selected-model="vm.selection"
                      service="abp.services.app.someservice"
                      on-select="vm.onSelect()">
```

In accordance with best practices for reusable components, this directive will isolate its scope (I'm omitting ancillary stuff like templateUrl for clarity):

```
    app.directive(
      'restBackedSelector',
      [ function () {
          return {
            scope: {
              selectedModel: '=',
              service: '@',
              onSelect: '&'
            }
          };
      ]);
```

Now here's the problem: `$scope.selectedModel` needs to be passed, in turn, to `ui-select` via the template:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedModel" ...>
```

This won't work because passing a model from the top level of `$scope` will break the binding when the `ui-select` controller changes its value, due to that [well-known gotcha](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html) of Angular scope inheritance.

What's the recommended way of working around this?

Here's a demonstration of the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/XjGuXSjWFEfG4eyZL6sR?p=preview

Changes made by selecting an item in the dropdown are not reflected in the scope of the directive nor the top-level app controller.  One partial workaround is to uncomment paged-select-box.js line 26, which will explicitly update the outer scopes by handling the on-select event.  However, even then, changes originating in the outer scopes (such as hitting the reset button) won't be reflected in the ui-select scope.

Comment: Have you tried using ng-model directly with your directive. You can follow some instructions here https://www.nadeau.tv/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/

Comment: Can you make a plunker to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Isn't this what "transclude: true" is for in the directive declaration?

Comment: @gyc yep, edited the question.  url is http://plnkr.co/edit/XjGuXSjWFEfG4eyZL6sR?p=preview

Comment: @KoolShams Correct me if I'm wrong, but that article only describes the use of NgModelController for parsing form element values into data models and vice versa, that is to say formatting data models to present them as HTML, all of which occurs within a single scope.  Can you explain how that applies to my problem, which is preserving a bidirectional model binding *between* scopes?

Comment: I added a couple console logs to try to examine your issue in detail, and I think your problem is something completely different.  It looks like the `ng-model` clause on the `ui-select` variant you are using isn't functional.  uncommenting the code in the `onSelect` definitely shows that the changes on the inside reach the outside;  conversely, setting `ng-model` to some other variable shows that variable never updates.  The "well known problem" you are mentioning here generally only affects primatives, not objects, and does not seem to be what you are suffering from.

Comment: @Claies I think you're mistaken.  If I add code to copy `$scope.selection` into, say, `$scope.model.selection`, then use `ngmodel="model.selection"` in the `ui-select` tag, the binding works properly even without the `onSubmit` handler: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7qqD2dwEW4oMvNAtI2J?p=preview Of course, that means that there's no binding between the top-level app selection and `scope.model.selection` in  `paged-select-box`, so it's only another partial workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a hierarchy of directives that inherit properties (or pass down properties) your first reflex should be to not use a `scope` property but a `bindToController` property.

The benefits are:

- You don't need to worry about isolated scopes.
- You're following best modern practice
- Attributes are automatically bound to the directive's controller so
  you get a clean object dot notation.
- The pain you were having with scope magically goes away

[From the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2XCjt9I0wS6RR4wmGAS9?p=preview):

```
controllerAs: 'vm',
scope: {},
bindToController: {
    selection: '=',
    requestFormat: '&',
    itemFormat: '&'
}
```

And with `controllerAs` the template needs to follow:

```
inner selection: {{ vm.selection.full_name }}

<ui-select ng-model="vm.selection"
           on-select="vm.onSelect($item)">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter search term">{{ vm.itemFormat({ item: $select.selected }) }}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in vm.items"
                       refresh="vm.requestFirstPage($select.search)">
        <span ng-bind-html="vm.itemFormat({ item: item })"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: Mixing the model's representation in with the attributes for the controller's internal state feels... icky.  But I can't argue with the practical upsides; this is definitely the best solution I've seen.